# GeneratorExit in Python generator

Tags: python, generator

I wrote a test program about Python generator. But I got an error that is not expected. And I don't know how to explain it. Let me show you the code:

```
def countdown(n):
    logging.debug("Counting down")
    while n > 0:
        try:
            yield n
        except GeneratorExit:
            logging.error("GeneratorExit")
        n -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = countdown(10)
    logging.debug("value: %d", c.next())
```

I thought it should run without any problem. But the output is:

```
# ./test.py
[2015/06/16 04:10:49] DEBUG    - Counting down     
[2015/06/16 04:10:49] DEBUG    - value: 10 
[2015/06/16 04:10:49] ERROR    - GeneratorExit
Exception RuntimeError: 'generator ignored GeneratorExit' in <generator object countdown at 0x7f9934407640> ignored
```

Why is there an error at the last line. I don't know why I triggered the GeneratorExit exception. Is there something aobut generator I missed? I also typed the code into interactive python shell, and everything is OK. How can this happen?

Answer (score 41):

Suppose you have the following generator:

```
def gen():
    with open('important_file') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

and you `next` it once and throw it away:

```
g = gen()
next(g)
del g
```

The generator's control flow never leaves the `with` block, so the file doesn't get closed. To prevent this, when a generator is garbage-collected, Python calls its `close` method, which raises a `GeneratorExit` exception at the point from which the generator last `yield`ed. This exception is intended to trigger any `finally` blocks or context manager `__exit__`s that didn't get a chance to run.

When you catch the `GeneratorExit` and keep going, Python sees that the generator didn't exit properly. Since that can indicate that resources weren't properly released, Python reports this as a RuntimeError.

Comment: Might want to mention that one way to ensure that the `RuntimeError` can be avoided by adding a `raise` statement after the `logging.error("GeneratorExit")` statement to re-raise that exception.

Answer (score 8):

When the generator object is garbage-collected at the end of your program, its `close()` method is called, and this raises the `GeneratorExit` exception inside the generator. Normally this is not caught and causes the generator to exit.

Since you catch the exception and proceed to yield another value, this causes a `RuntimeError`. If you catch the `GeneratorExit` exception you need to either reraise it, or exit the function without yielding anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It's because your's yield value n is inside try blocks which always returns new n reference which make the last n value is garbage collected automatically. It's also state in [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) :

> "Add support to ensure that close() is called when a generator iterator is garbage-collected"
>
> "Allow yield to be used in try/finally blocks, since garbage collection or an explicit close() call would now allow the finally clause to execute."

Since close method in generator is equivalent to throw a GeneratorExit and catched by yours exception, then `logging.error('GeneratorExit')` expression is executed.

"RunTimeError" is raised because the generator is yield next value n(9), it's state in python documentation https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods :

> "Raises a GeneratorExit at the point where the generator function was
>   paused. If the generator function then exits gracefully, is already
>   closed, or raises GeneratorExit (by not catching the exception), close
>   returns to its caller. **If the generator yields a value, a
>   RuntimeError is raised**. If the generator raises any other exception,
>   it is propagated to the caller. close() does nothing if the generator
>   has already exited due to an exception or normal exit"

May be the code should like this :

```
#pygen.py

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s \
        %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='[%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S]')

def genwrapper(func):
    #makes gen wrapper
    #which automatically send(None) to generator
    def wrapper(n=None):
        f = func(n)
        f.send(None)
        return f
    return wrapper

@genwrapper
def countdown(n=None):
    logging.debug('Counting Down')
    while True:
        try:
            n = yield(n)
        except GeneratorExit as e:
            logging.error('GeneratorExit')
            raise e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
    c = countdown() #avoid function call in loop block (avoid new reference to c)
     while n > 0:
         a = c.send(n)
         logging.debug('Value: %d', a)
         n -= 1
```

then in yours terminal :

```
guest@xxxxpc:~$ python pygen.py 5
```

will result :

```
[2018/12/13 16:50:45]         DEBUG - Counting Down
[2018/12/13 16:50:45]         DEBUG - Value: 5
[2018/12/13 16:50:45]         DEBUG - Value: 4
[2018/12/13 16:50:45]         DEBUG - Value: 3
[2018/12/13 16:50:45]         DEBUG - Value: 2
[2018/12/13 16:50:45]         DEBUG - Value: 1
[2018/12/13 16:50:45]         ERROR - GeneratorExit
```

Sorry for my bad english or my suggestion if not clear enough, thanks