# why is GeneratorExit raised by this combination of yield & exception suppressing ContextDecorator?

Tags: python, generator, yield, contextmanager

My goal is that instead of writing

```py
for item in items:
    with MyCD():
       ... # processing logic
```

I would like to have a single line

```py
    for item in MyCD.yield_each_item_wrapped(items):
        ... # processing logic
```

However, despite my `ContextDecorator` suppressing errors by returning `True` in `__exit__` on error, the `yield`ing the item after an item that raised error it immediately gets a `GeneratorError`.

So it seems that despite having handled the exception raised, the generator's `.close()` is called.

I'm running python 3.11.4

I would have expected to continue processing the remaining two items, as I deliberately suppressed the raised exception, i.e.: as the below snippet does

```py
def yield2(items):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        with MyCD():
            if item:
                raise Exception("my error")
            yield i  # yield success


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raising_flags = [True, False, False, True]
    expected = [1, 2]
    actual = [i for i in yield2(raising_flags)]
    assert expected == actual, (expected, actual)
```

---

```py
import traceback
from contextlib import ContextDecorator


class MyCD(ContextDecorator):
    @classmethod
    def yield_each_item_wrapped(cls, items, **kwargs):
        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            print(f"yield_each_item_wrapped {i=}")
            print(f"yield_each_item_wrapped {item=}")
            with cls(**kwargs):
                yield item

    def __enter__(self):
        print("__enter__")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, exc_tb):
        print("__exit__")
        if exc:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return True  # do not propagate


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raising_flags = [True, False, False, True]
    expected = [1, 2]
    actual = []
    for i, raising in enumerate(MyCD.yield_each_item_wrapped(raising_flags)):
        if raising:
            raise Exception("my error")
        actual.append(i)
    assert expected == actual, (expected, actual)
```

produces

```
yield_each_item_wrapped i=0
yield_each_item_wrapped item=True
__enter__
__exit__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 12, in yield_each_item_wrapped
    yield item
GeneratorExit
yield_each_item_wrapped i=1
yield_each_item_wrapped item=False
__enter__
Exception ignored in: <generator object MyCD.yield_each_item_wrapped at 0x7f42e625aac0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise Exception("my error")
RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise Exception("my error")
Exception: my error
```

Comment: Does making this a single line solve a real problem or is it just an academic question? The `for`/`with` version is much more effectively expressing your intent.

Comment: The context decorator in question is a centralized error handling logic, so it would be important to use it everywhere consistently and easily.
There are a quite a number loops, sometimes nested. 
If I can't have it in a single line, I need two levels of nesting for each, which is error prone (think copying), not to mention people just falling back to writing a for loop with no care for error handling. Sure, we can catch it in PR review but that's human and thus fallible 

Also, I really hate when I don't understand what python does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GeneratorExit in Python generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862196/generatorexit-in-python-generator). Essentially the generator's `.close` method is always called.

Comment: Not really. My problem is I would expect the same behavior from my code as in this example below (I'll add this snippet to the main question):
```
def yield2(items):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        with MyCD():
            if item:
                raise Exception("my error")
            yield i  # yield success


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raising_flags = [True, False, False, True]
    expected = [1, 2]
    actual = [i for i in yield2(raising_flags)]
    assert expected == actual, (expected, actual)
```

Comment: I'm not going to try to decipher the code you pasted into your comment but the answer to your question: *Is there a way to avoid that? [`.close` being called]* is no. The answer in the linked question explains why.

Comment: I've moved the comment's code into the main body of the question when posting the comment, should have deleted from there too. Now I also realize the question might be misleading, so I removed the 'avoid (.close being called)' part of the question, and included a code snippet of the behavior I would expect to happen. hope this clarifies.